# Maximal solution's interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Good day.
I'm trying to figure out the maximal interval of definition for the solution of this Cauchy Problem

[image: Cauchy Problem]

Being alpha a real number. No existence theorem seems to be right with this case. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Do you know the Picard-Lindelof theorem?

Comment: I know it. But I don't really know how to demonstrate Lipschitz's condition...

Comment: Well, writing $y'(t)=F(t,y(t))$ you need to show that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous in its second argument. This involves finding some upper bound for $$\frac{|F(x,y_1)-F(x,y_2)|}{|y_1-y_2|}$$

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how to proceed. With that, P-L Theorem gives information about an unique local solution... But I need to find the largest interval of solution.

Comment: The largest interval of solution is the largest interval in which the Lipschitz condition holds.

Comment: Since the rhs is well-behaved, it suffices to show that a solution cannot blow up in finite time. Consider that (for $t > 0$)
$$|y(t)| = \left|
 t^2 + \alpha +
  \int_0^t y(\tau) (1 - \cos(y(\tau) - \tau^2)) \, d\tau \right| \leq
|t^2 + \alpha| + \int_0^t |y(\tau)| \, d\tau$$
and apply the generalized Gronwall inequality.